# Allow cross site post request on specific ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I am using a complex template for my new ASP.NET Core application. Now I wanted to create a new controller which receives a POST request from another external server. That didn't work. I tried a lot until I found out that there is a mechanism set up which only allows POST request to access my controller which have a certain header (X-XSRF-TOKEN). This is done to prevent a Cross-Site-Request-Forgery attack.

However one specific controller should allow such requests, because this controller is not used from the webpage visitors browser. Is there a way to annotate the controller or any other way to allow this exception?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer and it is indeed possible by using an annotation. Just annotate your controller or action with **[IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute]** and the whole XSRF mechanism won't bother your controller any more.

Answer (score 1):

Note that even if you don't intend to use that controller action from a browser, if it can be accessed via http, it may easily be susceptible to CSRF. An attacker may still for example create a rogue webpage, which if visited by one of your users, makes the user send a request to that action. If session management is cookie-based or equivalent *and* the action changes server state, it would still be an exploitable vulnerability.

So while you can turn of CSRF protection, you need to consider consequences carefully.